# Dreamweaver Nav Bar and drop down not lining up correctly

Tags: html, css

I think I may have some code restricting itself. Basically I am new to this whole web creation thing and I am a bit stuck with the navigation and drop down. it doesn't seem to line up correctly. Here is my code below so far.

So I have: Home - NewToFitness? - Nutrition - Recipes - Contact all on one line and workouts on the next line, underneath the word 'Home'. I want it on the same line as the others but I can't find where my code has gone wrong.

```css
.mainHeader nav {
  position: relative;
  background: #363636;
  height: 60px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -border-radius: 5px;
}
.mainHeader nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.mainHeader nav ul li {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
}
.mainHeader nav a:link,
.mainHeader nav a:visited {
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 110.5%;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 14px 60px;
  height: 30px;
}
.mainHeader nav a:hover,
.mainHeader nav a:active .mainHeader nav .active a:link,
.mainHeader nav .active a:visited {
  background-color: #73b5ff;
  text-shadow: none;
}
.mainHeader nav ul li a {
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: relative;
}
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #363636;
  min-width: 20px;
}
.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1
}
```

```html
</head>

<body class="body">

<header class="mainHeader">
<img src="img/Logo.png" width="100" height="100" alt=""/>
    <h1>Mike's Workshop</h1>
<nav id="navbar"> 
    <ul>
 <li><a href="Home/Home.html">Home</a></li>
 <li><a href="NewToFitness/NewToFitness.html">New to Fitness?</a>       </li>
    <li><a href="Nutrition/Nutrition.html">Nutrition</a></li>
    <li><a href="Recipes/Recipes.html">Recipes</a></li>
    <li><a href="Contact/Contact.html">Contact</a>   </li>    
    <div class="dropdown">
     <a href="Workouts/Workouts.html">Workouts</a>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="#">Abs</a>
            <a href="#">Back</a>
            <a href="#">Biceps</a>
            </div>
            </div>
   </ul>  
  </nav>

</header>
```

Comment: Please, describe your problem and provide us a minimal, complete and verifiable example. You can use stacksnippets or tools like jsfiddle.net

Comment: The CSS indicates that you should be using a list structure `ul` & `li` but these do not exist in your HTML...start there,